# try & except not working in Django APIView

Tags: django, api, exception, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have written logic to delete an item in the apiview of Django. The logic is to assign that item to a variable and by using Try and Except. It works fine when there is an object but when there is no object I got an error saying **"leads.models.Lead.DoesNotExist: Lead matching query does not exist."**

I should be getting a message of Deal doesn't exist with 400 status as I had that inside Except. I am getting 500 errors in the post.

```
def delete(self, request,pk, *args, **kwargs):
    id = pk
    lead = Lead.objects.get(id=id)
    # abc.delete()
    # return Response({"message": "Lead has been deleted"},
    #                 status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    try:
        lead = Lead.objects.get(id=id)
        if lead.delete():
            return Response({
                "message": "Deals has been deleted"
            },status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
    except lead.DoesNotExist:
        return Response({
            "message": "Deal doesnt exist"
        },status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My urls is:

```
path('lead/<int:pk>', ChunksLeadCreate.as_view()),
```

I hope this code is enough to fix the issue.

Comment: I tried as you said but still getting the same 500 error in the postman.

Comment: You have another `lead = Lead.objects.get(id=id)` call that is outside the try block. That could cause the 500

Comment: Just tested it as well, I was wrong. You can also use `lead.DoesNotExist` (from the instance) but this will only work if you do manage to get the object and end up with a `lead` object, so it's still better to use it from the model class (`Lead.DoesNotExist`)

Comment: yes, that was creating the problem, i got it. But why the assignment outside can cause errors??  got confused....??

Comment: Because if the id you use does not exist, and the get() call is outside the try, then django will raise 500 by default.

Comment: local variable 'lead' referenced before assignment , got this error with small lead. But works with Lead.Doesntexist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented out the assignment of lead before Lead.Doesnot exist and it worked.

```
 def delete(self, request,pk, *args, **kwargs):
        id = pk
        # lead = Lead.objects.get(id=id)
        # abc.delete()
        # return Response({"message": "Lead has been deleted"},
        #                 status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        try:
            lead = Lead.objects.get(id=id)
            if lead.delete():
                return Response({
                    "message": "Deals has been deleted"
                },status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        except Lead.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({
                "message": "Deal doesnt exist"
            },status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```